# How to make javafx stage resizable only in height?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a stage and I want to let user change only its height, but not the width. The only solution I found is `stage.setResizable(false);` but it also doesn't allow to change height. How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set a fixed width with:

```java
stage.setMaxWidth(x);
stage.setMinWidth(x);
```

If you then set the stage to resizable, you should only be able to resize it in its height.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have a more versatile approach especially if your program is using FXML. To do that we can bind the min and max width to be fixed to itself, thus non-adjustable by the user.

```java
stage.minWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
stage.maxWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
```